# Gradle support missing from Eclipse Neon (4.6)

Tags: eclipse, gradle

According to https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship the buildership gradle support should be backed into Eclipse neon. But its missing from the J2EE edition at least.  I.e. there is no option to import a gradle project (e.g. grails 3 project).

Anyone else noticed this?

I will try installing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misreading that page.

There are a large number of projects which are part of the 'Oxygen' and 'Neon' overall projects but that does not mean they are included in the downloaded releases. It just means they are fully tested as part of these releases, but they may have to be installed separately.